# Anybody know how to save multiple contacts to android phone using programming

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am developing a contact based app,which saves contact list fetched from webserver to users phone contacts.Is it possible to save multiple contacts to users phone contact? If yes then please provide me details.

Answer (score 0):

found in another post but should work.

```
private void addContact() {
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op_list = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null) 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null) 
        //.withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT) 
        .build()); 

// first and last names 
op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) 
        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Second Name") 
        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "First Name") 
        .build()); 

op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "09876543210")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
        .build());
op_list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)

        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "abc@xyz.com")
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
        .build());

try{ 
    ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op_list); 
}catch(Exception e){ 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
}
```

full post, source and example at [Cannot insert android contacts programmatically into android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576185/cannot-insert-android-contacts-programmatically-into-android-device)