# How to create Contact to Sim Programmatically in Android

Tags: android

```
private fun addContactToSim(number:String,name:String) {
    try {        
        val simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn")
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put("number", number)
        values.put("tag", name)
        context.getContentResolver().insert(simUri, values)
    }
    catch (e:Exception)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

This function I am using to create contact to sim am calling this function in  `onCreate()` with single contact   addContactToSim("MyTestNumber","9028340932")  like this but contact is not saving to sim I am unable to see contact in sim please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In general, I think you should use `int` for the number instead of a string!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContentValues` for creating contact in phone.have look:

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("tag", "Hey");
cv.put("number", "1234567890");
getContentResolver().insert(simUri, cv);
getContentResolver().notifyChange(simUri, null);
```

also add permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: no the given code is not working @Hemant Parmar i have create contact on Sim programatically

Comment: does this code saving number either in phone or SIM ?

Comment: nothing save this code neither in phone nor in sim @Hemant Parmar

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: i tried but this code i not working i tries this before same isse @Hemant Parmar

Comment: well it may be other issue. you have to manually check restriction about SIM contact.

Comment: OK can you tell me how to Save all field to create contact to sim like what will key name  if i will save firstname ,lastname,email,profilepic ,organisation and all...

Comment: @no i am not getting any error or Exception but some time i the contact create some time its not please suggest for other field how i will add

Comment: no i am not getting any error or Exception but some time i the contact create some time its not please suggest for other field how i will add @Hemant Parmar i am stucking in this issue from long time please suggest

Comment: did you say sometimes its working? i.e its working right? on which device you test your app ?

Comment: i am giving you some reference, hope it will help you, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576283/5110595) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744514/5110595)

Comment: LeTv its working  but for not always its some time i dont know what is wrong with this can you please tell me how to add other field to create contact in sim

Comment: for save name & email have look [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-contacts-programatically-using-contacts-provider-in-android-example/)

Comment: but in my case please check how i will add in Sim not i have add phone book contact i want to add only on Sim @Hemant Parmar