# How to add contacts programmatically

Tags: android

How to add contact using programming I'm trying this :

```
public void addContact(Contact contact)
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("contact_id", contact.getContactId());
    values.put("lookup", contact.getLookupKey());
    values.put("mimetype", StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    values.put("data1", contact.getStructuredName().getDisplayName());
    values.put("data2", contact.getStructuredName().getGivenName());
    values.put("data3", contact.getStructuredName().getFamilyName());
    values.put("data4", contact.getStructuredName().getPrefix());
    values.put("data5", contact.getStructuredName().getMiddleName());
    values.put("data6", contact.getStructuredName().getSuffix());
    context.getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

Comment: then try that. if gives error, post it here

Comment: Where are you trying to add the contact..? Are you trying to add the contact to your app from android contacts or you are trying to add contacts to android contact?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add contacts programatically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096186/how-to-add-contacts-programatically-in-android)

Answer (score 15):

The best way to do this is to use `ContentProviderOperation`, not to use `ContentValues`. Use that function:

```
private void addContact() {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
    operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI) 
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null) 
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null) 
            .build()); 

    // first and last names 
    operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE) 
            .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Second Name") 
            .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "First Name") 
            .build()); 

    operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0) 
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "09876543210")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
            .build());
    operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) 
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)

            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, "abc@xyz.com")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
            .build());

    try{ 
        ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList); 
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

**Note:** Please import that to your class file `import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;`

Good luck.