# Android Save Contact by click button event

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, contacts

I want to make a button that when its clicked it creates and saves all the person's information such as name, email and phone # into the contact list without opening the contact form or hitting save, code is in Java.

```
EditText name;
EditText phone;
Button addContact;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    name = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    phone = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone2);
    addContact = findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);

    addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            if(!name.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()){


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone.getText().toString());


                if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) !=null){
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }

    );
}
```

}

Comment: do you have any code to show? please don't expect full implementations at Stackoverflow

Comment: @PedroAGSantos I added the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096186/how-to-add-contacts-programmatically-in-android there is some similar answer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [`ContactsProvider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider). You'll see how to use it and some examples.